# Nuxt.js: Can I add a class using a ternary operator based on a Boolean from a prop?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I'm trying to use a Boolean in a prop to add a class based on a ternary operator. I'm obviously not doing it right because it is always evaluating to false.

```html
<div :class="$style.inner + ' ' + (isRight == true ? 'is-right' : 'is-false')" :style="`color: #` + fontColor"></div>
```

If it's true, I need `is-right` added to the class, otherwise, this doesn't need to be added.

```js
props: {
   isRight: {
      type: Boolean,
      default: false
   },
}
```

index.vue

```html
<Signpost isRight=true/>
```

```css
.is-right { padding-left:20% }
```

Looking at their [Docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html#Passing-a-Boolean), I'm not sure I can do this with a Boolean actually.

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen sorry with added parentheses still always evaluating to false.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually had a little syntax error for my prop that needed binding:

```
<Signpost :is-right="true"/>
```

And then on the div as @kissu said:

```
<div :class="[isRight ? 'is-right' : '']"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try passing the prop as `:is-right="false"` to have it passed down as **Boolean** and not as a basic **String** (`is-right="false"`).

For the class, it can be written like as [shown in the docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html#Array-Syntax)

```html
<div :class="[isRight ? 'is-right' : 'is-false']"></div>
```

That way, you will even be able to do a strong equality check: `isRight === true` (comparing boolean to boolean).

VueJS devtools can help you see the type (thanks to the color).

---

There are some strongly recommended prop name casing recommendation that can be found here: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/style-guide/#Prop-name-casing-strongly-recommended

```js
props: {
  greetingText: String // camel-cased here
}
```

```html
<WelcomeMessage greeting-text="hi"/> <!-- kebab-cased here -->
```

---

Also, feel free to write [ES6 template litterals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals), it may help the lecture. A working solution would be:

```html
<div :style="`color: #${fontColor}`"></div>
```

Can also be done for your `class`, but I didn't want to risk a bad interpolation here.

Comment: I did not get the question. Can you phrase it in some other way ?

Comment: If the prop isRight is set to true, like in the above example, I need a class added which adds 20% padding to the left. I can't see how this adds that class for me. Nonetheless your syntax help has been very appreciated.

Comment: I have edited my answer. The syntax can be pretty tricky (I have to often go check it myself) but the documentation is bae on this one.

Answer (score 1):

To pass a Boolean to a prop you need to use v-bind or : like this:

```
<signpost v-bind:isRight="true" />
```

or

```
<signpost :isRight="true" />
```

Also if the only possible values for `isRight` is true or false you can shorten your ternary to just be:

```
:class="isRight ? 'is-right' : 'is-false'
```